# Liferay request current page name

Tags: java, liferay, portal

What is the smartest way to get current page name where request came from? By page I mean the real page name that contains current portlet.

Comment: Are you sure you mean name and not title?. I never understand the difference, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

By using something like that you should be ok

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
String title = themeDisplay.getLayout().getName(themeDisplay.getLocale());
```

Answer (score 1):

just be aware,themeDisplay.getLocale() could result different char encoding format, use with caution, may cause certain string functions to fail