# Access bare page name in Liferay template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'm trying to emit the current page's name within portal_normal.vm. The options I know of all include a bunch of XML garbage that it's important to be rid of.

Right now, I'm using $layout.getName(), which produces this:

```
<root default-locale="en_US" available-locales="en_US">
    <name language-id="en_US">
        Home
    </name>
</root>
```

It's true that the page's name is "Home", but the rest of that garbage ruins it.

I've tried $layout.name as well, but it produces the same result.

How do I access the bare value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923459/liferay-request-current-page-name) (which appears to be about writing controller or servlet code), I was able to produce this code to get the bare name:

```
$layout.getName($themeDisplay.getLocale())
```

Comment: +1 Layout.getName and Layout.getTitle are both localised so require a Locale to retrieve just one version, otherwise it returns all localised versions in XML